# How to change database details in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, high-availability

I want to change my database connection URL dynamically. This is to support High Availability. I will get event when some master node is down and new DB IP will be updated. Now is it possible in JPA to update this connection using entity manager factory. Currently we are using hibernate JPA implementaion.

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?

You may want to look at a database driver solution (e.g. http://ha-jdbc.github.io/) which essentially proxies your jdbc requests, but be used to configure clustered and failover database(s).

Comment: we are using MySql db. We are handling HA using zookeeper. So will get event when ever primary db is changed. So we need to make it work according to the current system.